# Culture currency format de-CH gives Fr. instead of CHF - How to get CHF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, currency, culture

I have changed the culture in an asp.net page to get the currency as Swiss Currency as following:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="SalesProjects.aspx.cs"
 Inherits="admin_UsersManagement" Culture="de-CH" UICulture="de-CH" %>
```

I have formatted the string in the grid as

> {0:C0}

Unfortunately instead of "CHF" I get "Fr." and I have not found a way to get what I need even with the other variations of the culture (de-CH (German) fr-CH (French) it-CH (Italian) rm (Raeto-Romance)).
Any hint on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does the entire site run with that culture or just that page? Also, are you using .NET 4.5 or 4.0?

Answer (score 3):

You can manually override it in `Global.asax`:

```
<script runat="server">

protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo cInf = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-CH", false);

    cInf.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "CHF";

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cInf;
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cInf;
}

</script>
```

Comment: You might consider using [CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture.aspx) and it's UI equivalent instead/as well, provided the app is .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property ISOCurrencySymbol

```
RegionInfo region = new RegionInfo("fr-CH");
var cur = region.ISOCurrencySymbol;
```